# Focus or scroll for panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have search box which give me result more than 20 results .. with previous and next button I am able to go to next or previous string .. but my page wont move ..

```
launch: function () {
    Ext.define('MyViewController', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
        alias: 'controller.myview',

        // This method is called as a "handler" for the change color button in our view
        onnextClick: function () {
            var mypanel = this.lookupReference('mypanel'),
                header = mypanel.getHeader();

            header.setStyle('background-color', '#FFEFBB');
            header.el.down('div.demo-title').setStyle('background-color', '#ccc');
 header.el.down('div.demo-title').focus(); // I want to do like this 

        }
    });
```

Can you please tell me how to set scroll or window focus ?

Comment: How are you supposed to focus a `div`?

Comment: ok. but how to do that